# Bash - Passing arguments with "$@" to either 'sudo su' or 'sh'

Tags: bash

I have a server where shell commands to the supervisor-service must be executed by the specific user `lx`. I have written a bash function that does exactly that.

```
function supervisor {
if [ `id -nu` != lx ]; then
    sudo su - lx -c "supervisor \"\$@\"" -- supervisor "$@"
else
    sh -s "$@" <<EOF
supervisor "$@"
EOF
fi
}
```

It works, but it's doesn't look clean and I'm not really comfortable with half the things I'm using here.

How can that function be written in a less convoluted way?

Answer (score 3):

The only simpler way to do this I've come up with is just to `sudo` every time and not worry about whether you're already the right user or not.  But overall it seems pretty straight forward and it should work fine as-is.  Some other suggestions:

- Indent your code with the function.  Leaving the heredoc alone is ok.
- Use `[[` for conditionals.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306115/79839 for more context.
- It is more modern to use `$()` for subcommands instead of backticks (``` `` ```).  Parenthesis `()` are also used for creating subshells so the `$()` is just substituting the result of a subshell.

Comment: I don't think that [unix.se] answer provides any argument that `[[` should be preferred to `[`.  I'd argue against using `[[` if that's the only Bashism (which it can be, if we remove the unnecessary `function` keyword).  Then we can make it a plain POSIX shell script and let `/bin/sh` execute it (for portability and efficiency).

Comment: The `[[` syntax came from `ksh` and it is a good habit to get into.  Maintainability matters more to me than portability to things that don't have `bash` or `ksh`.

Comment: In what way do you consider `[[` better than `[`?  Most of the time, I find its unusual parsing rules annoying rather than helpful (e.g. variable names expanded without any `$`).

Comment: I still think avoiding the problem of empty variables causing missing argument errors is a good idea.  http://www.tothenew.com/blog/foolproof-your-bash-script-some-best-practices/ and https://github.com/progrium/bashstyle agree with me.

Comment: Running all commands with sudo won't let me start `supervisor` as `lx`. But it **must** be `lx` to correctly run `supervisor`. That is the reason why I've written that function to start with.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to simply give an error if it's invoked as the wrong user (or even better, not provide the function at all, similar to hiding admin programs away from non-root users in `/sbin` rather than `/bin`).  That allows a user to then consider whether they are typing into the right terminal (and any other issues), and if appropriate, issue their own `sudo` or `fakeroot`.

Consider this version (with the single Bashism removed, to make a portable script, and with shellcheck errors addressed):

```
supervisor() {
    if [ "$(id -nu)" != lx ]
    then
        echo "supervisor: can only be run by user 'lx'" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    command supervisor "$@"
}
```

I removed the use of the pointless inner shell - that just serves to expand arguments a second time (similar to using `$*` instead of `"$@"`) which probably isn't what you want.  Instead, I use the `command` builtin to make the shell find a non-function version of `supervisor`.

---

If you really must invoke `sudo` from within the script, then we can simplify a bit.  If users are allowed to `sudo` an arbitrary command (which they should be able to, if they can `sudo su`), then we can make the function invoke it like this:

```
sudo -u lx -- supervisor "$@"
```

That seems cleaner than creating a shell and funnelling arguments through it.

Comment: - I need to open a inner shell on **that** system because: I only get all the necessary environement variables to run supervisor when a shell is started.

Comment: - I switch to lx for our users, because I don't want to bother them when it's clearly unnecessary.

Comment: If you really, really need an inner shell (because you can't set the environment variables any other way - but why not?), then you'd want to quote the script you're providing - i.e. `<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF`.

Comment: what difference does it make if I put `<<'EOF'` instead of  `<<EOF`?

Comment: [If any part of *word* is quoted, ... the here-document lines shall not be expanded. ((Otherwise)), all lines of the here-document shall be expanded for parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04).  We need the here-document to be preserved as we wrote it, for the inner shell to perform expansions.